# Iterating over the Hashmap in Set views

Tags: java, algorithm, selenium, data-structures, hashmap

There is a Map which consist n values associated with m keys. I am getting the keys and associated values from WebElements. so far; 
key : [1, 2, 3] 
value : [A, B, C, D, E, F, G] 
 
But the problem is;
Key [1] : value [A,B,C] 
 key[2] : value[C,D,E] 
 key[3]: value [F, G, H] 
So a single key is associated with number of values. See below example.

```
<tr key="key1" >
    <td x=""value1">
    <td y=""value2">
    <td z=""value3">
   </tr>
   <tr key="key2" >
    <td x="a">
    <td y="b">
    <td z="c">
 </tr>
```

How to design hashmap which will view values associated to particular keys in set view.
For Ex: Key [1] : value [A,B,C] 
 key[2] : value[C,D,E] 
 key[3]: value [F, G, H]

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: maybe you use a hasmap with a key and a String-Array: `HashMap<String,String[]> h = new HashMap<String,String[]>();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Define your `Map` as follows:

```
Map<String, String[]> tds = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
```

This way for each key you can have an array of values.

Comment: Yes, we are doing the same. But actually we're unable to iterate through like; Before putting into hashmap how we tell the map object that particular key is holding number of values as String objects.
while (key1/key2) then String[1] = value1; String[2]=value2; String[3]=value3;
While fetching the values we need filtering the keys with it's value, so it seem design the problem in a way to get key/value pair.

Comment: Can`t understand what you need. :(

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question then you can

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
// Or use 'Set' in place of 'List' if values are unique for a given key.

// putting values in map
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("key1 String1");
list.add("key1 String2");
list.add("key1 String3");
map.put("key1", list);

list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("key2 String1");
list.add("key2 String2");
list.add("key2 String3");
map.put("key2", list);

list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("key3 String1");
list.add("key3 String2");
list.add("key3 String3");
map.put("key3", list);

//adding another value for key1
list = map.get("key1");
list.add("key1 String4");

// fetching from map
// list = map.get("key1");
System.out.println(map.get("key1")); // prints : [key1 String1, key1 String2, key1 String3, key1 String4]
System.out.println(map.get("key2")); // prints : [key2 String1, key2 String2, key2 String3]
System.out.println(map.get("key3")); // prints : [key3 String1, key3 String2, key3 String3]
```

**Note:** HashMap will not maintain order of keys.

Comment: Yes, we are doing the same. But actually we're unable to iterate through like; Before putting into hashmap how we tell the map object that particular key is holding number of values as String objects. while (key1/key2) then String[1] = value1; String[2]=value2; String[3]=value3; While fetching the values we need filtering the keys with it's value, so it seem design the problem in a way to get key/value pair

Comment: I have updated my answer. In that I am putting values in map and retrieving same from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use an external library, you could do this with Guava's [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). If you want to preserve iteration order and no duplicates can appear as values (against a given key), using [`LinkedHashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html) should work:

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = LinkedHashMultimap.create();
multimap.putAll("1", Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
multimap.putAll("2", Arrays.asList("C", "D", "E"));
multimap.putAll("3", Arrays.asList("F", "G", "H"));
```

Testing this with

```
System.out.println(multimap);
```

yields

```
{1=[A, B, C], 2=[C, D, E], 3=[F, G, H]}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is how to store these many keys an object so we can pass into hashmap keys. Before hashmap keys they are the list of values. keys are list of values and I can not hardcode through, so would you please suggest me how putAll() method

Comment: If your keys are in a list of values, how do you know the key->values mapping beforehand?